# stuck in violet screen or black screen with dash

Tags: login, freeze

Since I've installed ubuntu 12.04 I have this problem (on mint 13 I also had this problem) now I have ubuntu 12.10 updated and windows 7 with it.

When I go to windows everything works fine but some times suddenly if I choose ubuntu, it will stuck in violet screen. Even the login screen wont come and I should press and hold the power button to reset my laptop I have to do this for 3 or 4 times.

After reseting and choosing ubuntu again a black screen come and there is a dash in it and nothing else. I'm woried about my lap top . if I reset it again I'm afraid it could get serious problems.

My laptop is hp probook 4520s 1GB swap space.

Comment: Could you add an image of the `violet screen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue when Ubuntu automatically does a check disk.  Sometimes it doesn't actually display that it is doing it.  It appears like it is hanging, but if I let it go it completes after a while and let me log in.  If I reset it before it finishes, it just tries again on next boot, so I have to let it finish the first time.

Have you tried leaving for say 20-30 mins? See if it is doing a check in background.

If so, can you log in after pressing ctl-alt-F1 ?

If you can, log in via command line and type dmesg. See if it sheds any light.

Comment: tnx for the answer . in a few times  when i left it for 30 min it went to login page but often when i left it for an hour nothing happend . but now i have installed 12.10 32 bit and as soon as i choose ubuntu in 10 sec i can see login winodw !!!

Answer (score 0):

hi i have solved my problem i have searched alot and i figured out that some cpu struction wont work fine with 64 bit operations and my problem was that my o.s was ubuntu 64 bit 12.10 and last night i have installed ubuntu 12.10 32 bit and it works really awesome ....

i hope that this answer was helpfull for anybody that they have this problem too.!

Comment: my lap top battery died and after I removed it and I'm working plugged in all the time that I want to start my laptop it stuck on violet or black screen . it's driving me crazy . I left my laptop for 1 hour but it just stucked in that screen . I guess its grub problem . can anybody help me out ?